# How can I fix this "module not found error" while trying to run the code after successfully installing sqlite3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, npm

I managed to install sqlite3 module at first but got some errors like "module not found", but now I have to edit the post thoroughly since I got the errors below after I tried to reinstall sqlite3 (npm install sqlite3). Here is the output:

```
PS D:\testsqlite3> npm install sqlite3
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

> sqlite3@5.0.1 install D:\testsqlite3\node_modules\sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.1/napi-v6-win32-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@5.0.1 and node@15.5.1 (node-v88 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2015
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.8.30804.86) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.1321) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v141
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.17763.0
gyp ERR! find VS - msvs_version does not match this version
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
gyp ERR! find VS - "2017"
gyp ERR! find VS - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:340:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:376:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1063:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=D:\\testsqlite3\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\napi-v6-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=D:\\testsqlite3\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\napi-v6-win32-x64" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=6" "--node_napi_label=napi-v6" "--msvs_version=2015"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\testsqlite3\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v15.5.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=D:\testsqlite3\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=D:\testsqlite3\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6 --msvs_version=2015' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\testsqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:376:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1063:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:295:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\testsqlite3\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd D:\testsqlite3\node_modules\sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v15.5.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=D:\testsqlite3\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=D:\testsqlite3\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6 --msvs_version=2015' (1)
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\testsqlite3\package.json'
npm WARN testsqlite3 No description
npm WARN testsqlite3 No repository field.
npm WARN testsqlite3 No README data
npm WARN testsqlite3 No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@5.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@5.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-10T20_45_12_903Z-debug.log
```

I also installed visual studio and build tools again and again but nothing changed.

Comment: Is there more to that error stack? And if you try `npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source` does that fix things?

Comment: @ZacAnger I tried that, but it didn't work either. I also edited the post and added the full error code.

Comment: Is there anything under `node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding` at all?

Comment: no, just an empty folder named "napi-v6-win32-x64".

Comment: What's the output of npm install sqlite3? And if you're using an IDE, consider reseting it maybe

Comment: So the `.node` binary isn't getting built at install time. Have you tried updating Node and npm to the latest versions? I see lots of issues on the sqlite3 repo about this, with varying degrees of resolution.

Comment: I updated Node but it didn't work either. I also edited the post again since this time I get errors while installing sqlite3. It was successful but now I can't install it either.

Comment: Can you try installing it with `npm install sqlite3 --loglevel silly`? This will give even more log output which may be helpful. You could also try manually setting the path to msbuild as in [this comment](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1663#issuecomment-535049449).

Comment: @ZacAnger Same again, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, I have tried many different ways, even updating node and npm, I also installed vs and python again, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two days of attempts, I have finally produced a solution, and want to share it in case someone else faces the same problem. Here are the steps:

1. Visual Studio 2019 installation(with C++ Desktop Development),
2. node-pre-gyp installation:

```
npm i node-pre-gyp -g
```

3. msvs version configuration setting (enter the path manually because npm gives error finding it):

```
npm config set msvs_version "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
```

4. npm sqlite3 installation:

```
npm install sqlite3
```

It perfectly works now.